# how to start session in iPhone to generate the number of session start for a particular event

Tags: ios6

i have three field in sqlite database table POOL_A,POOL_B,and POOL_C in poool A i have starting  first questions and Pool B and POOL C are empty i have to create a session for a particular concept code like DC_C1  and also  have to find number of session completion for a particular means SESSION_NUMBER FOR DC_C1, I am sending the algorithm for more understand the problm

- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {

  ConceptShoeViewController *show = [[ConceptShoeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConceptShoeViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:show animated:YES];

  [self selectPoolDatabase];

  int countA=lA.count;
  NSLog(@"count a @%d",countA);
  NSLog(@"question of A %@",lA);

  int countB=lB.count;
  NSLog(@"count b @%d",countB);

  int countC=lC.count;
  NSLog(@"count c @%d",countC);

## pragma mark algorithm on session create........

```
NSArray *cookieJar = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
for( NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieJar)
{
    if( [[cookie name] compare: @"SESSION_NUMBER"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {

    }
}


if (countA+countB <= 10)
{
```

## pragma mark add all question from A and B

```
    [mainArray addObjectsFromArray:lA];
}
```

else if (countB<10)

```
{
 if (countA<10)

{
```

## pragma mark add all question from A and remaining from B

```
}
    else
    {
```

## pragma mark add all question from A

```
    }
}
```

else
{